# How can i make an scheme as seems as a tree using html or bootstrap?

Tags: html, visualization

I need to make a schema like bellow using html or bootstrap. I've been searching websites, but none of them give me any answer that looks like this schema.:
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNI6c.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio, you can try [Mermaid js](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/n00b-gettingStarted). You need to know basic HTML, CSS, Javascript and Markdown for using it.

Comment: Can i use this in angular?

Comment: I'm personally not familiar with Angular, but the internet says it works just fine, just research for a proper implementation. You can start with [this article on Medium](https://singhprabhanshu5.medium.com/flow-chart-using-mermaid-in-angular-501e53565075) . 
If my answer is helpful for you, consider to accept it as a solution 

Comment: I think your solution is the best solution i found. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read this one: https://medium.com/technical-writing-is-easy/diagrams-in-documentation-markdown-guide-4e78419e8d2f